# How to ignore SQL retry policy in unit test?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2, retrypolicy

I have inherited `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` from [Code sample by Microsoft in GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.SqlServer/SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy.cs), called `MySQLServerRetryPolicy` class

I have added a cancellationtoken in `ShouldRetryOn` overriden method in `MySQLServerRetryPolicy`, so I could kill the NET.Core console by pressing Ctrl+C. Here is the code snippet below:

```
protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception) {
        _retryCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();}
```

Here is how I use `MySQLServerRetryPolicy`:

```
                builder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString, options => {
                options.ExecutionStrategy(exeStrategyDependencies=>
                                              new MySQLServerRetryPolicy(
                                                  exeStrategyDependencies, _errorNumRetryList, RetryCancelToken.Token));
```

`builder` variable above is type of `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

However, in the unit test, there is no output telling if the SQl retry policy running forever.

Question:
How do I ignore or skip the SQL retry policy in the unit tests?

Comment: i wouldn't inherit from the `SqlServerPolicy` it really pollutes your mysql stuff.

Comment: @DanielA.White, sorry I do not get your comment. Do you mean that you would avoid inherit from `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` ?

Comment: ShouldRetryOn returns a bool. If you don't want to retry, return false. It's not clear from this question, but assuming you want to use your production bootstrapping code in your test, you can add a condition based on the environment before adding the retry policy. But if you're having troubles with the retries it's probably not a unit test.

Comment: yes inherit from ExecutionPolicy

Comment: what are you unit testing? perhaps you should use the in memory provider.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have in memory provider & SQL in unit test. I am required to use SQL as part of my unit tests.